# how to bind model to kendo grid datasource

Tags: model, kendo-ui, schema, datasource, kendo-grid

i have developed a web application using asp.net mvc4 and kendo ui tools..

in there i need to **bind a model to grid datasource or schema** directly without creating fields in schema..

here is the code of my grid..

```
function LoadGridView() {

        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "Items/ReadItemDetails",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "Items/InsertItemDetails",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "Items/UpdateItemDetails",
                    Type: "POST",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "Items/DeleteItemDetails",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },

            batch: true,
            pageSize: 30,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ItmKy",
                    fields: {
                        ItmCd: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                        ItmNm: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                        Unit: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                        isAct: { editable: true, nullable: true }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

i need to pass a model name to schema instead of this lines

```
schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ItmKy",
                        fields: {
                            ItmCd: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                            ItmNm: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                            Unit: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                            isAct: { editable: true, nullable: true }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

i tried like this but then the grid is not working..

```
schema: {
                    model: @Model
                }
```

can somebody please help me and tell that how can i **bind a model to schema or to DataSource** if possible..

here is the model class

```
namespace KendoModel
{
    public class ItemMas_LookUp 
    {
        public long ItmKy { get; set; }
        public string ItmCd { get; set; }
        public string ItmNm { get; set; }
        public int UnitKy { get; set; }
        public int isAct { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }

        public ItemMas_LookUp() 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in pure JS, no backend components:

My model:

```
var PageItem = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "Id"
});
```

My data source (in the same scope!):

```
var pageItemDs = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        ...
    },
    schema: {
        model: PageItem
    }
});
```

If you wish to use the ASP.NET components, you will need to define the grid itself in Razor, you wont be able to mix JS and Razor like you are trying to.

Comment: i guess your answer should work but actually my problem is i need to bind a model which i created using a separate class.. please refer the code of model class which i mentioned at last of question and then please tell me how can i bind that to grid..

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, you will need to create the grid with Razor - I haven't done that before. Look at their documentation. :)

Comment: if so the can you please tel me the way that i can bind the model if i create the grid with razor.. please help me because i'm new to this..

Comment: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html - click on the ASP.NET MVC link below the demo. There is example code on how you can do it.